# gunicorn service rewriting environment path

Tags: path, gunicorn

I am trying to configure gunicorn to serve a django app, and it was working (although not serving css & js files). While attempting to fix that issue, suddenly gunicorn has stopped working. I have followed the instructions in this article:
https://pylessons.com/django-deployment

and it was serving the html content, but after playing with file permissions trying to fix the issue of not loading css & js (journal was indicating permission denied) it now is failing to start the service.

The gunicorn service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=stiofan
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/stiofan/www/b_end/portfolio
ExecStart=/home/stiofan/www/.env/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        smccaffrey.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but the journal records:

```
Jun 22 14:35:16 stiofaniridian systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jun 22 14:35:16 stiofaniridian systemd[5051]: gunicorn.service: Failed to locate executable /home/stiofan/www/b_end/.env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Jun 22 14:35:16 stiofaniridian systemd[5051]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/stiofan/www/b_end/.env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Jun 22 14:35:16 stiofaniridian systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 22 14:35:16 stiofaniridian systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The part which caught my attention is in the first few journal lines where the failure happens. The path in the service file points to `/home/stiofan/www/.env/bin/gunicorn` but the path it is trying is `/home/stiofan/www/b_end/.env/bin/gunicorn`

I have tried to find any matching questions on here as well as on the web in general but none seem to address this problem.
The file & directory permissions have all been set, temporarily, to 777 but the problem persists.
The working directory in the service file points to `/home/stiofan/www/b_end/portfolio` so I can't see why its looking in the wrong place.